# How to appear my app in YouTube share via list?

Tags: android

YouTube App for tablets has a sharing-option. For example: I watch a video in the YouTube app and click the button to share. Bluetooth, Googlemail, and Dropbox appear for me. I wonder how i can list my app there? Which intent-filter has my app to have?

Here i have tried. But this is not working for me. I am using Android Kitkat version.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this intent filter  inside an Activity tag in your Manifest file...

```
<intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:mimeType="image/*" /> /* WRITE THE CORRECT TYPE */
    </intent-filter>
```

Then you have to develop the way your Activity handles the data from the current intent.