# Make my app appear in YouTube share?

Tags: android, youtube, share, intentfilter

I know this has been asked quite a few times, but I have tried the answers and non of them worked. This is my current intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

The answers I was looking for were [android youtube: share a youtube video TO my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178041/android-youtube-share-a-youtube-video-to-my-app) and [How to appear my app in YouTube share via list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185159/how-to-appear-my-app-in-youtube-share-via-list)

But for some reason they don't work for me. I've tried many alternatives, using android:host, using different schemes, specific mime types. I only need to get the url of the youtube video once I click share to my app. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in your manifest file (I just tried ;)).

source:[Youtube intent filter & scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256003/youtube-intent-filter-scheme)
more info:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! I'm confused as to why originally, when I was using text/* mime it didn't work. 
Thank you!

Comment: This is working, but i need my app to appear only on YouTube. By Adding text/plain my app option is also visible on google Photos App.I don't want my App to be visible for sharing photos.

Comment: @king please give the solution if you have implemented App sharing option to be visible only on Youtube